# Metal camera housing sparking on a metal building

Tags: electrical

When installing a camera with a metal housing on a metal building powered up by a POE switch located on a different building, sparks are generated when the metal housing touches the metal building. Why would this occur?

Comment: Is there a mains feeder connecting the two buildings? Where are you on this planet?

Comment: I know there is a circuit breaker panel on the outside of building that powers the POE switch, not sure about the building that has the camera. Buildings are 50' apart. Project is a mini storage in South Texas and has eight buildings.

Comment: Are you actually using a PoE injector, or did you just stick a wall plug on an Ethernet cable?

Comment: The manager said there is a main feed behind all the buildings in a grassy area that he believes serves at least those buildings in the back area of the property. There may be another feed in the front area of the property. He's not sure.

Comment: Actual 8 channel POE switch

Comment: Can you figure out if the building that has the camera has power to it or not and get back to us?

Comment: Yes there are lights on that building

Comment: @CamGuy -- is the panel on that building fed with 3 wires or 4? If you turn the breaker feeding the lights on the culprit building off, does the sparking stop?

Answer (score 1):

### Treat grounding seriously

This is a "canary in the coal mine".  And what its warning you to do is do a *serious* evaluation of the Grounding Electrode System for each of the buildings.  However I would advise only a cursory inspection - that the Grounding Electrodes are present and intact, and that the main panel has an intact neutral-ground bond - until you have evaluated and eliminated from suspicion the PoE camera. See if they have done something dumb like grounding one side of the PoE.  (If the injector grounds one side, and a load grounds the other, poof!)

If the PoE injector and camera check out on the bench, *then* do an exhaustive search of the complex's Grounding Electrode System - ground rods on each building, netural-ground wired separately to each building with N-G bonds definitley absent in subpanels, etc. Start putting GFCI breakers/devices on circuits under suspicion. Etc.

### Grounds first, then circuits

Other than that, this sounds like the classic "I hooked up the circuit and it works, but when I hook up the grounds the circuit fails. What's wrong with my grounds?"   The grounds are fine. This is a perception problem: the circuit is actually dangerous, and ground is protecting it.  If you hook up ground first, then you see things as they actually are... because connecting live conductors  is the last thing you do, so the problem is obviously there.

So ground that box.  Then hook up the camera!  The problem will "move" to where it actually is.

Comment: The PoE switch has a ground screw on it. We grounded it to the electrical plug box. Should we also install a ground rod and connect both to the rod?

Comment: Then I would also carefully check the integrity of grounds on that branch circuit powering the PoE switch/injector.   You may have a neutral-ground bootleg or a missing ground wire somewhere.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I will pass it along to the OWNER.

Comment: Yeah, I'd also check the ground wires in the feeders between buildings as well -- this sounds like there's a large common-mode voltage difference across the Ethernet link